# how to show ToastEvent from external utils.js file

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created function in external utils.js file which I have exported to use in LWC, in which I am dispatching showToastEvent but I am getting an error :

```
Uncaught Error during LWC component connect phase: [ShowToastEvent is not defined]
```

here is my code :

utils.js

```
export function dispatchShowToastEvent(THIS,TITLE,MESSAGE,VARIANT,MODE) {
THIS.dispatchEvent(
    new ShowToastEvent({
            title: TITLE,
            message: MESSAGE,
            variant: VARIANT,
            mode: MODE
        })
);}
```

LWC :

```
import { dispatchShowToastEvent } from "c/utils";
renderedCallback() {
    dispatchShowToastEvent(this,'Error!!','Please enter at least 2 characters.','error','pester');     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `utils.js` you use `ShowToastEvent` but you never imported it. To fix the issue just add the related import.
If you want to export more than one function you could use `export { function1, function2, ..., functionN }` sintax:
`utils.js`:

```js
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

const dispatchShowToastEvent = (componentReference, title, message, variant, mode) => {
    componentReference.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
        title,
        message,
        variant,
        mode
    });
};

export { dispatchShowToastEvent };
```

`THIS` could be misunderstood, so I changed it to `componentReference`.

Comment: Thanks @RubenDG, It works.